# My input only read three commands and does nothing with the ones it reads?

Tags: java, input

I have to write a user interface that takes in data from the command screen and uses it to access methods in my linked list class. They are both in the same file and the node class was already written and it compiles fine. If anyone can help me figure out why it only reads three commands, such as i dog, i cat, p and then says java.io.IOException: Stream Closed. I also checked if adding spaces i.e. commanding i dog cat, i bird, p affected the amount of lines it read and it didn't. The exception was also the same. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    linkedlist link= new linkedlist();
    int n=0;
    System.out.println("Type a command\n");
        try{
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            s=in.readLine();
            while(in.readLine()!=null){
                s=in.readLine();
                char first=s.charAt(0);
                int space= s.indexOf(" ");
                while(space<=n){
                    if(first=='i'){
                        String w=s.substring(space);
                        link.insert(w);
                    }
                    if(first=='d'){
                        String w=s.substring(space);
                        link.delete(w);
                        link.printlist();
                    }
                    if(first=='f'){
                        String w=s.substring(space);
                        link.find(w);
                        link.printlist();
                    }
                    if(first== 'p'){
                        link.printlist();
                    }
                    n++;
                }
                in.close();
            }
            }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Ack!: " + e);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stream closed error means you are trying to write to in after it has been closed.  Format your code like this:

```
Open in stream on this line before try
try {
    Do processing here
    .....
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   ....
}
finally
{
     close stream here
}
```

The finally block will run code that needs to run after running try/catch, so put the stream close there.

Comment: Thanks solved that problem but now it doesn't output anything. Should i output in the finally block. I wouldn't think so but I'm really confused.

Comment: What part is not outputting - the Ack in the catch or the "Type a command" or something else?

Comment: Can you update the main post with your linkedlist code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to move `in.close();` outside after the `while(in.readLine()!=null)` loop. Currently, BufferedReader `in` is closed inside the while loop, so when while loop tries to check the `in.readLine()!=null` condition, it actually tries to access the already closed `in`.

Comment: thanks for the help. But now it won't output anything. Even though in my linkedlist class, printlst contains System.out.println